# Why my software can't create a socket file outside of the home folder on Ubuntu 20 subsystem?

Tags: windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I run some software on Ubuntu 20 subsystem that creates some data files a socket file `get.ipc` in the home directory:

[image]

But if I run the software with another data location like `/mnt/i`, for example, where `I:` is another NTFS volume, the software creates its data files, but can't create 'get.ipc' file showing the error message

```
Fatal: Error starting protocol stack: listen unix /mnt/i/.ethereum/geth.ipc: bind: invalid argument
```

And with `/mnt/c` I get the same result.

What can be a difference between the home folder (that is `C:\Users\D-Ef\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.Ubuntu20.04onWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc\LocalState\rootfs\home\def`) and `I:` folder?

Is it possible that the home folder has some special permissions that allow to create socket files, for example? How to check this?

I tried to create a symbolic link from my home directory to `/mnt/i/.ethereum` with a command like

```
ln -s /mnt/i/.eth/ /home/def/.eth
```

but this does not help.

`LocalState` has the following additional permission but it is not clear what is it:

[image]

Comment: I am unfamiliar with how WSL works, but whenever I have seeing issues like this in Linux, it needed up being either a blatant permissions issue or an SE Linux issue.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 WSL is a typo, I corrected the title.

Comment: “WSL is a typo, I corrected the title.” Odd. I added the WSL to the title for clarity. If you are using “Windows Subsystem for Linux” as your tag indicates, then WSL is [the accepted acronym as per Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux).

Comment: Are you sure, NTFS can carry UNIX sockets at all? Remember: The WSL home directory is not plain NTFS

Comment: @EugenRieck yes, it can. The software works in the home directory, see the first picture.

Comment: As the accepted answer shows, NTFS does not, only WSL home does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of file you're trying to create is known as a Unix socket (type `AF_UNIX` or `AF_LOCAL`).  That's a socket that's located in the file system.

WSL supports Unix sockets.  It has to, because many Linux programs require them to work.  Windows, as of recent versions, *also* supports Unix sockets.  However, the two types are incompatible.

If you're using a Unix socket with a WSL program, you need to create it in the Linux file system area.  That means that it should not be under `/mnt/<drive>`.  If you're using a Unix socket with a Windows program, that Windows program should create it outside of the WSL area.

The difference is that the Linux file system area used by WSL supports proper POSIX semantics: case sensitivity, arbitrary byte file names, Unix sockets, POSIX permissions, dangling symlinks, and so on.  The standard NTFS area used by Windows does not support those things, and so cannot be used to store Unix sockets created and used by WSL.  All of the drives specified under `/mnt/<drive>` in WSL are Windows drives and hence not suitable for WSL Unix sockets.